# Detecting white retro reflective tape in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'd like to detect white retro reflective tape with opencv. I tried this program, but it doesn't work well as it highlights everything, and not just the tape.This is what the tape looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9TLn.jpg

Code so far:
https://hastebin.com/uqejihemic.py

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to place a light source next to your camera or use a flash. That'll make retro-reflective tape shine much brighter than everything else in the frame.

Comment: Showing your code or any text as an image is a no-no on here - edit your code into your question, correctly indented.